# Insert more than 1000 rows in SQL table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have code that gets thousands of object ids from a website and I noticed that I was only able to write up to 1000 rows in a SQL Table using this code. How do write more than 1000 rows into a SQL table? The data I am inserting the table is not coming from another database, it is dynamically generated from other code.

```
var conn = new SqlConnection(masterData.DictRunData["ConnectionStringLocalDb"]);
const string objectName = "NotAvailable";
var dt = DateTime.Now;
var cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into CorporateDataStructure.dbo.ObjectInventory (location, object_name, object_id, object_xpath, time) values (@location, @object_name, @object_id, @object_xpath, @time)", conn);

foreach (var pair in webidsAndXPaths)
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@object_name", objectName));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@object_id", pair.Key));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@object_xpath", pair.Value));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@time", dt));

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
return true;
```

Comment: `How do write more than 1000 rows into a SQL Table?` -- Have more than 1000 elements in `webidsAndXPaths`

Comment: You should use [SqlBulkCopy](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/122498/using-sqlbulkcopy-for-high-performance-inserts/) if you want any sort of performance with bulk inserts.

Comment: Consider using the same connection for bulk insert, instead of opening and closing connection for each insert. You should also look for `SqlBulkCopy`

Comment: Why only 1000 rows? At first glance nothing says you can not do more than 1000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var conn = new SqlConnection(masterData.DictRunData["ConnectionStringLocalDb"]);
            const string objectName = "NotAvailable";
            var dateTime = DateTime.Now;

            // create the datatable
            var table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("location", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("object_name", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("object_id", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("object_xpath", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("time", typeof (DateTime));

            // then loop all dictionary entries and add the rows
            foreach (var pair in webidsAndXPaths)
            {
                table.Rows.Add(location, objectName, pair.Key, pair.Value, dateTime);
            }

            // finally write the data to the sql server
            using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.ObjectInventory";
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(table);
            }
```

Answer (score -4):

Try to open and close the connection outside your loop, like this:

```
conn.Open();
foreach (var pair in webidsAndXPaths)
{
    //your code here
}
conn.Close();
```